# How to disable particular time slots in timepicker material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, timepicker

So i have a array of timeslots from which i want user to pick a time
lets say

```
var arr = ["11:00:00","11:10:00","13:00:00"]
```

how can i disable other time slots from timepicker and only enable this time slots

My TimePicker

```
<TimePicker
      label="Time"
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
    />
```

Array of TimeSlots i want user to pick from

```
var timeSlots = [ "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30", … ]
```

Actaully im getting this timeslots array from api

Comment: Can you show us more code?

Comment: @niceman im using select now it will be great if you can help

Answer (score 0):

Hey Ronak you can use Filter() function of ES6 to get limited or particular timeslot. Try to use filter while fetching the timeSlot from API.
If you still face any error just lemme know.